# CSS how do you blend the bottom of an image into a background?

Tags: css

Hello I am trying to get the effect that I have done in photoshop, but get the same result as photoshop but using only css.

http://jsfiddle.net/10b2d5qg/

[image]

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Unphotoshopped image
  </p>
  <img src="https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/2022/07/09/c71b7102-f1ec-41b5-8362-5597256779ce/team-fortress-2.jpg" />
  <p>
    Wanted effect
  </p>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TAZ8DIM.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) CSS properity and a [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient), i.e.:

```html
.thumbnail {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, transparent);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. After googling for a bit I didn't see mask-image coming up as a css property to use. Thanks! Will accept when the timer for accepting runs out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask-image` & `-webkit-mask-image` with `linear-gradient`

```css
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding:10px;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
        mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}


p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Unphotoshopped image
  </p>
  <img src="https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/2022/07/09/c71b7102-f1ec-41b5-8362-5597256779ce/team-fortress-2.jpg"/>

  
</div>
```